# Elpy-rpc in Emacs gives 'exited abnormally with code 1' error and unexpected output. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, emacs, conda, elpy

#### emacs elpy-20230402.1946 started giving me strange errors relating to its elpy-rpc:

"error in process sentinel: elpy-rpc--default-error-callback: peculiar error: "exited abnormally with code 1"

And this cryptic error message:

**Output from Backend**

**There was some unexpected output from the Elpy backend. This is**

**usually not a problem and should usually not be reported as a bug with**

**Elpy. You can safely hide this buffer and ignore it. You can also see**

**the output below in case there is an actual problem.**

**Output**

**[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Unrecognized alias: 'W', it will have no effect.**

**[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization: Error loading argument W=['ignore'], values whose keys begin with an uppercase char must be Config instances: 'W', DeferredConfigString('ignore')**

It appears communication with elpy-rpc has broken down, and it constantly beeps whenever it is supposed to offer auto-complete suggestions, etc, elpy is now unusable for me as I cannot type a single word without it constantly complaining.

This error appeared out of nowhere after I upgraded emacs packages today (May 31, 2023). I also upgraded my conda base environment, but I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem or not, but my python and ipython executables installed with conda work just fine. The environment variables are set correctly. I have no idea even where to start with this sort of error.

Is there a way to fix this or maybe downgrade elpy until this problem is fixed?

I tried editing a python file and expected normal functioning of this emacs package. I can't think of anything that changed other than my usual emacs package upgrades and upgrade of conda environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [elpy issue 1729](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1729)?
In particular the answer of *Krisselack* did the trick for me.

TL/DR

What worked for me:

- in emacs do a `package-delete` on elpy
- in the `.emacs.d` directory remove everything related to elpy
- restart emacs
- re-install elpy

Comment: Not sure why, but that did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1936#issuecomment-954994911) to [elpy issue 1936](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1936) fixed this for me.

Namely, `M-x elpy-rpc-reinstall-virtualenv`.